# Missing VCRUNTIME.dll and MSVCP.dll error

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-c++, dll

I'm making a personal Unity project. There was no problem with the editor view, and even the build was successful. But when I try to execute the exe file, following errors happen:
(Sorry for the Korean)

[image: Error Message 1]
[image: Error Message 2]

It says that I'm missing the `MSVCP140_APP.dll` and `VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll`, but as you can see in the pictures, there ARE these dlls.

How do I fix it? I want to test my game with the build version, not only with the editor.

I already tried reinstalling `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` x64 and x86 both, the online solution. Rebooting the computer also did not work.

Comment: But they aren't ending with `_app`.

Comment: @CoderCharmander Oh my, you maybe got the point. I'll try it out.

Comment: looks like you used Store App libraries for a desktop application.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Then how do I fix it?

Comment: you need to provide more details about your project

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not much aware of the detail of my project, since I didn't deliberately add some kind of references or dll to my unity project. What information is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
#endif
```

Bugs like this makes me hate Unity3D, you need first place the code above somewhere,

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
SetDllDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Plugins"));
#endif
```

and call it in the very beginning stage, for example in your GameStart.cs, before any possible other DLLImport could be called.

Comment: My target platform of build setting was for the "Universal Windows Platform", which seems to have caused the error. I just changed it to Standalone, then it fixed. Anyway thanks for the answer!